# Is "correspondingly" used here correctly?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, conjunctions

> The importance of Internet access grows each day, **correspondingly**, web
>   content accessibility too becomes equally important to ensure it meets
>   the needs of users with disabilities.

**correspondingly** - connecting word, agreement/addition/similarity.

I would just like this confirmed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even dropping the 'too' leaves problems. A comma splice and a false comparison (surely access to both is equally important; both needs are increasing in parallel).

> The importance of Internet access grows each day; the importance of
>   web content accessibility, to ensure that the needs of users with
>   disabilities are met, grows correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using ***correspondingly*** in that way is fine. But if you include it you do not need ***too*** as it is duplicatory, though in a slightly different sense.

I would also place a comma or perhaps semi-colon after *important*.

Comment: I realized that a while ago, the "too" was a small mistake. Thanks for helping me out. I am glad I confirmed that my grammar skills are still up-to-date.